# initramfs unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Tags: initramfs

I have a R100 Toshiba external CD-Rom using pci card and usb floppy.  I have tried to install XP to see if it works any different and to do that I have to use recovery disks for the Toshiba to make a X: drive and then use winnt to put files on hard drive and install from there other wise if it tries from the cd I get a blue screen. So is there anyway to do something similar to ubuntu?  I have tried older versions and slow burns of the image.

Comment: Are you sure your post is related to Ubuntu in anyway? Actually what you trying for?

Comment: he's asking why this happens when he tries to install ubuntu. it happens for me with a number of distributions prior to 11.04.

Comment: I have a hard time to understand @John is trying to do. Who is voting this stuff up?. The message in the title indicates errors in the Grub boot options or a faulty hdd.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1.Pull out the ATA which links to CD-ROM and hard-drive,then exchange the head of the ATA(in my situation: the longer one) on your CD-ROM with the head of the ATA on the hard-drive.

2.Restart the computer